# Not able to build scripts from local machine onto jenkins

Tags: jenkins, devops

I have created a simple python file project.py on my desktop in ubuntu 22.04.2

I tried to build a simple free project on Jenkins and in the execution shell I wrote the location of the python file then apply and saved it.

When building it showed failure. What is the reason and what should I write in the execution shell.

I have given the required file permission with chmod 777

Error msg-

Build step Execution shell mark build as failure
no such file

Comment: `chmod 777` is not "the required file permission", `chmod u+x` is sufficient. "no such file" suggests you are not in the right location.